# import and export mysql table to xml file in windows command?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

am using Mysql server version "MySQL Server 8.0".
please help me, how to export and import mysql table to xml file, in windows command prompt.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Export** 
$ mysql -uroot -p --xml -e 'SELECT * FROM rajdb.Tablename' > /tmp/raj.xml

**Import**
mysql> LOAD XML /tmp/raj.xml INTO TABLE Tablename;